# Stacked autoencoders for data denoising with keras not training the encoder?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I looked for several samples on the web to build a stacked autoencoder for data denoising but I don't seem to understand a fundamental part of the encoder part:

- https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html

Following the examples I built the autoencoder like that:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, 50))
encoded1 = Dense(30, activation="relu")(inputs)
encoded2 = Dense(15, activation="relu")(encoded1)
encoded3 = Dense(5, activation="relu")(encoded2)
decoded1 = Dense(15, activation="relu")(encoded3)
decoded2 = Dense(30, activation="relu")(decoded1)
decoded = Dense(50, activation="sigmoid")(decoded2)
autoencoder = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded3)
autoencoder.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
autoencoder.fit(trainX,
    trainX,
    epochs=epochs,
    batch_size=512,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    validation_data=(trainX, trainX))
```

On the examples there is mostly a model with the encoder and a seperate model with the decoder. I always see that only the decoder model get's trained. The encoder is not trained. But for my usecase I only need the encoder model to denoise the data. Why does the encoder need no training?

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation about encoder-decoder is wrong. Encoder encodes your input data into some high dimensional representation which is abstract but it's very powerful if you want use that as features for further prediction. To make sure encoded output is as close to your actual input, you have decoder which decodes your encoded high-dimensional input back to original input. During training, both encoder and decoder are involved i.e. the weights of the encoder layers and decoder layers both are updated. If the encoder is not trained how it's going to learn the encoding mechanism. During inference, you use only the encoder module as you want to encode the input.

Comment: Does this mean when I train the model "autoencoder" in my code above, the weigths of the model "encoder" get adjusted, too? Because of shallow copying and so on?

Comment: Yes the weights for both encoder and decoder get updated or else how will the encoder learn to encode the input

Comment: @Andrej If you feel that my post answers your questions can you accept my answer